# Offline availability of .pdf while using PDF.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

My problem is the following:

I use `PDF.js` to display a `.pdf` on a website. However the `.pdf` must be included from some `url`. That means, that if one downloads the website for offline purposes, the `.pdf` will not be included and therefore can not be displayed. Thus I wonder, whether it is possible to embed the `.pdf` (e.g. in an `html`-container), so that it can be found by `PDF.js`. In this case, offline mode would be easy to achieve.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I think I had made a mistake. I think that if you save a webpage for offline usage it will save all files which are related to the page via href and src attribute

Comment: Ok, but what is your suggestion now? My problem is that I don't know how to include the .pdf beside from an url/path (originally). And if I know that .pdf from an url only, how could I operate on it even if it would be saved?

Comment: I think that when you save your page, it will save the pdf in the folder related to the page

Comment: Yeah, but if I get it right, the point is that in this case the CORS issue arises. I. e. that access to the .pdf ist not given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can't be achieved without using a localhost (or a browser plugin etc.).